# Solaris 10 keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard, solaris-10

Im runing Solaris 10 - but im having problems with the keyboard.

Instead of - i get /, and instead of y i get z, etc. I tried changing every option in the menu "Keyboard Behaviour". I also tried changing kmdconfig from xorg to xsun, but then the graphics goes all wild and ugly - although the keyboard works fine then. Also cant change resolution in xsun mode.

By the way, im runing Solaris from Vmware, but i doubt this has anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the graphic environment to the console:

```
dtconfig -d
dtconfig -reset
```

Select the correct keyboard layout you use:

```
kbd -s
```

Load it:

```
loadkeys
```

Check the keys are working properly. If okay, enable the graphical environment again:

```
dtconfig -e
```

If that still works, make that choice persistent after a reboot by updating your eeprom. eg:

```
eeprom kbd-type=Spanish
```

Comment: How do i get to console? At login screen, choose Command Line Login?

Comment: I already wrote it. You do it with the dtconfig commands posted.

Answer (score 0):

1. This should be migrated to superuser.com
2. It seems that you are expecting a german keyboard layout but are getting a US layout - at least the differences you are seeing are differences between those layouts. I don't know where to change that in openSolaris, but maybe it helps you find the correct place to look. Whatever desktop environment that you are using, it should have a tool to change the keyboard layout, probably somewhere with the other internationalization settings.